# Incomplete output of pickle.load in Python

Tags: python, pickle

I am making a game and I want to export and import the terrain. It's a 100x100 grid (2d list of numbers). At first, I export it to a `save.dat` file using `pickle.dump( )` and then i import it using `pickle.load( )`.

But in console I see something like this:

```
Data: [[1, 3, 4, 4, 11, 5, 8, 13, 8, 10, 12, 7, 6, 6, 9, 13, 7, 5, 1, 2, 12, 7, 6, 9, 13, 7, 5, 0, 1, 12, 8, 10, 12, 8, 13, 0, 7, 9, 4, 11, 6, 9, 4, 4, 13, 7, 9, 4, 13, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 3, 4, 10, 12, 0, 0, 8, 10, 12, 1, 3, 13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 13, 1, 3, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 10, 3, 11, 9, 13, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 5, 7, 9, 13, 8, 11, 6, 5], [

...

], [12, 8, 11, 9, 4, 10, 12, 1, 12, 1, 2, 12, 1, 3, 4, 1 2, 12, 0, 8, 4, 4, 4, 13, 0, 7, 9, 4, 13, 8, 4, 11, 6, 9, 13, 7, 9, 10, 2], [7, 9,
```

It ends uncomplete. Here is my code:
(g is the grid)

```
    def export_data(self):
        with open("save.dat", "wb") as fout:
            pickle.dump(self.g, fout)
        print("Export successful!")

    def import_data(self):
        with open("save.dat", "rb") as fin:
            a = pickle.load(fin)
            print("Import successful!")
            print("Data:", a)
```

I think it may be caused by limited length of output but I don't know, how to make it better. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Did you try with a 10 by 10 grid perhaps? And could you include the full contents of Data and save.dat so we can reproduce easier?

Comment: With 10x10 it works fine. It really seems that it's something like limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the terminal that cuts off most of the lines.

But the whole 100x100 array is stored in the variable `a`. If you want to double check, you can check its length

```
print(len(a))
```

If you want your terminal to show all the lines, you can configure your code editor.

Comment: Yes, I found out it right now. When I write it to a file, it works fine and when I load it as a JSON object it works too. Thanks!